# flutter change data like angular behavior subject in entire app

Tags: angular, flutter

Angular Example

```
dataSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  CurrentData = this.dataSource.asObservable();
  ChangeProfileData(data) {
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }
```

but i want same functionality in flutter means
screen 1 add
data

and screen 2
automatically change data

like angular share data services for component

Comment: where is the `screen 1 ` and `screen 2`? please, adding the asserts to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this docs from official flutter docs.

[Simple app state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

Flutter contains multiple methods for state management

- setState
- InheritedWidget & InheritedModel
- Provider & Scoped Model
- Redux
- BLoC / Rx
- MobX

Here's detailed information about all the methods: [State management options](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).

In my last flutter project I'm using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package for passing data down to widget tree and ValueNotifiers, Streams, FutureBuilders and many more widgets for accessing that data. I suggest you to check official flutter docs and videos on YouTube for detailed info about state management.

If you have 33 minutes to learn something, check out [this Google I/O'19 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I) about state management.

Comment: I know these techniques pretty good but I want  rxdart behaviour like angular what is code can you provide me

Comment: @K24, I'm sorry I'm not using RxDart, please edit your question or ask a new one to get RxDart specific answers.